# PHP won't update MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code that is supposed to check whether or not a word is already in the database. If it is, it simply adds one to the number of times that a word has been chosen. If it isn't in the database, it adds it. The problem that I am having is that it is not updating my database. I have verified that everything is connecting properly, and it even echos the word that was chosen. It just wont update. My code is as follows:

```
<?php

include 'swearTrackDB.php';
$conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die ('could not connect');
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $conn) or die ('could not reach database');

if(isset($_POST['mash'])) {
$mash = $_POST['mash']; 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracker1 WHERE string='$mash'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {

    $sql = "UPDATE tracker1 SET count = count + 1 WHERE string = $mash";

}else{

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tracker1 ('string') VALUES ('$mash')";
}

}

?>
```

Please help! I cant figure this out and I've been searching for hours!

Thanks in advance

---

Even with updating my code significantly, this gives me no errors at all, but it is still not posting to the database. Anyone out there still willing to help me fix my dumb problem?

```
<?php

include 'swearTrackDB.php';
$conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die ('could not connect');
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $conn) or die ('could not reach database');

if(isset($_POST['mash'])) {
$mash = $_POST['mash']; 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracker1 WHERE string='$mash'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {

    $updatequery = mysql_query("UPDATE tracker1 SET count = count + 1 WHERE string = $mash");

    mysql_select_db('tracker1');
    $sql = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
    mysql_close($conn);

}else{

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tracker1 ('string', 'count', 'upvote', 'downvote') VALUES     ('$mash', '1', '0', '0')");

    mysql_select_db('tracker1');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
    mysql_close($conn);
}

}

?>
```

Comment: You are not using the `$sql` variable for anything.

Comment: I know, I tried getting rid of it and it didn't do anything so I kept them

Comment: To be clear: **you're not executing any `UPDATE` or `INSERT` query!**

Comment: I just removed them, no change. But thanks for helping me clean the code

Comment: Okay. So, you have no idea what you are doing. You should read [a tutorial or two](https://google.dk/search?q=php+mysql+tutorial) before asking about stuff you do not understand.

Comment: @deceze What do I need to do to it to execute it?

Comment: Call `mysql_query(..)`...!?

Comment: have you **used** `mysql_query($sql)` anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Aditya, are you blind? It's right there on the `select`. Just kidding, _I_ know you meant on the update/insert, but the OP may not :-)

Comment: Where did `mysqli_query` come from all of a sudden?! Hint: mysql and mysqli are two completely different things which don't work together.

Comment: Axiile, it's considered bad form to change the nature of a question in such a way that it invalidates answers. By all means _add_ information to the end of the question since then the answers to date still make sense. If you need to change the very nature, then it's a _different_ question and should be asked as such.

Comment: Axiile, I've incorporated your answer (which wasn't) into your question (which was). Please delete your answer. In any case, you're still using `'` for your column names rather than backticks - please reread my answer.

Comment: @paxdiablo I haven't used stack much other than researching other peoples questions. Sorry if i'm posting incorrectly

Comment: That's okay, most of us cut newcomers a fair bit of slack and it's been so long since I was low rep, I can't remember at what point you're allowed to edit your own questions :-) You're taking (hopefully constructive) advice without getting defensive, that's all anyone can ask for.

Comment: @paxdiablo I know you mentioned the duplicate key update, but you should know that this isnt going to hold account data and is, in every sense, a Mickey Mouse applicaition. Truthfully this is the first web app I'm ever building. Do you see anything in that code that needs to be fixed that may get this to work? I've been researching for hours and cant understand why my database wont update

Comment: @paxdiablo As of right now, I'm a web designer, not developer lol

Comment: Axiile, err, the quotes? I'll make that clearer.

Comment: @paxdiablo In the databse, "string" is exactly as it sounds, a string. The other three values (count, upvote, downvote) are all numeric values

Comment: Axiile, that's fine for the column _values,_ use quotes for string, no-quotes for integers. I'm talking about the column _names._ Single quotes can not be used there, only backticks. I'm hoping my answer edit makes that clearer, suggest you go have a look. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 3):

In your first code instance, I can see where you've executing the `select` query but updates and inserts don't get magically executed just because you put them into a string variable :-)

You need to call `mysql_query` on those as well.

But, in any case, this is a horrible idea in anything other than strict single-user environments since you have a race condition. Between your `select` and `insert/update`, someone *else* may come in and change the database underneath you.

I suspect a better option would be to use the `insert ... on duplicate key update ...` functionality of MySQL, as documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
insert into tracker1 (`string`) values ('$mash')
on duplicate key update `count` = `count` + 1
```

Note also the *backticks* on the column name, not single-quote marks, and you may want to (at some point) look up `sql injection` or `little bobby tables` to see why blindly using an unsanitised `$mesh` in your queries is dangerous in anything other than Mickey Mouse<sup>(a)</sup> applications.

Touching on the quotes a bit more in-depth, if you use `'` in your queries:

```
create table xyzzy (a int);
insert into xyzzy ('a') values (1);
```

you'll see something along the lines of:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
  version for the right syntax to use near:
    "'a') values (1)" at line 1: insert into xyzzy ('a') values (1)
```

Column names can be surrounded by *backticks* to protect them from the SQL parser but *not* quotes. That previous query would have to be written as:

```
create table xyzzy (a int);
insert into xyzzy (`a`) values (1);
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Mickey Mouse is a registered trademark of the Walt Disney Company but I'm more using it in the slang sense of "unimportant, trivial". Apologies to Disney in advance, I don't wish to weaken your trademark unnecessarily but, if you have a problem with my use, you might want to take it up with the American Heritage Dictionary :-)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code line

```
$sql = "UPDATE tracker1 SET count = count + 1 WHERE string = $mash";
```

with:

```
$updatequery = mysql_query("UPDATE tracker1 SET count = count + 1 WHERE string = $mash");
```

And this line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tracker1 ('string') VALUES ('$mash')";
```

with:

```
 $insertquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tracker1 ('string') VALUES ('$mash')");
```